# Open window by window.open and print it with window.print on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code like

```
var windowObject = window.open('','windowObject','arguments...');
windowObject.document.write("<html><body onload="alert(1);window.print();alert(2);"><div>some html</div></body></html>");
```

The problem is that everything works except the window.print event (on ie, on firefox, it's working).

Is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance,
Gaurav

Comment: Strange. Looks okay.... No errors?

Comment: Syntax highlighting fixes the error.

Answer (score 1):

It's a quotes issue: the double quote after `onload=` ends the string being written to the document. Change the onload quotes to single quotes. You also need to add a call to the `close()` method of the document:

```
var windowObject = window.open('','windowObject','arguments...');
windowObject.document.write("<html><body onload='alert(1);window.print();alert(2);'><div>some html</div></body></html>");
windowObject.document.close();
```

Comment: Ah yes, you need to call `windowObject.document.close()`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this line, it appears that you are trying to use nested double quotes:

```
windowObject.document.write("<html><body onload="alert(1);window.print();alert(2);"><div>some html</div></body></html>");
```

You more likely want to do:

```
windowObject.document.write('<html><body onload="alert(1);window.print();alert(2);"><div>some html</div></body></html>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is not allowing us to do print in newly opened window/tab. You can achieve your requirement by adding a new html file like this
`<body onload="window.print()"><div>Some html</div></body>`
and replace your code with `var windowObject = window.open('<path_to_your_new_html>','windowObject','arguments...');`